# How do I sum values by an ID and date, keeping the values ordered by date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in Python:

```
product_num    date       qty
001            1/1/2022     4
001            1/1/2022     2
002            1/2/2022     1
002            1/2/2022     3
002            1/3/2022     5
001            1/3/2022     5
003            1/1/2022     2
004            1/4/2022     3
004            1/4/2022     4
```

I'm trying to organize the data as follows (summing quantity by product ID and date):

```
product_num    date       qty
001            1/1/2022     6
001            1/3/2022     5
003            1/1/2022     2
002            1/2/2022     4
002            1/3/2022     5
004            1/4/2022     7
```

I tried using a group by and sum function but the part that I haven't been been successful in is keeping the product number in each row, maintaining the column headers, as well as keeping the product numbers and dates in order.

Comment: `df.groupby(['product_num', 'date'])['qty'].sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use groupby and sum

```
df.groupby(['product_num','date']).sum().sort_values('date').reset_index()
```

```
    product_num     date    qty
0   1             1/1/2022   6
1   1             1/3/2022   5
2   2             1/2/2022   4
3   2             1/3/2022   5
4   3             1/1/2022   2
5   4             1/4/2022   7
```

data used for the question

```
product_num date qty
001 1/1/2022 4
001 1/1/2022 2
002 1/2/2022 1
002 1/2/2022 3
002 1/3/2022 5
001 1/3/2022 5
003 1/1/2022 2
004 1/4/2022 3
004 1/4/2022 4
```

[image]

Comment: @Hannah, what is the format of your date?

Comment: This is similar to what I had originally done, but for whatever reason it's still separating each date out, i.e.: product number one on 1/1/2022 is showing up as 4 and 2

Comment: The date format is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: what should the output be like?

Comment: The output should ideally sum quantity for product 1 on date 1/1/2022, so 4 and 2 together, and only show one instance of product 1 on date 1/1/2022 with a quantity of 6

Comment: you are seeing just one row of product 1 for 1/1/2022 as 6. isn't it?

Comment: there are two rows for product 1, but those are on different dates, first one on 1/1/2022 and then on 1/3/2022.  you want to keep them separate. right?  Date 1/1/2022 is also for product 3 and appears in row 4

Comment: I'm still seeing every data line separated out, it's not summing by product number and date. I want to keep product 1 on two different dates separate

Comment: the result I posted was based on the date you shared. I just copy/pasted my notebook screenshot.  I'm sorry, if Im unable to follow you

Comment: Your output is exactly what I want, for some reason it doesn't work on my end. Interesting!

Comment: Check your data and try using the data posted here. There might be spaces or non-white characters in your data. Trim all spaces and then try it out

Comment: Tried with the data and it still doesn't return correctly, I'm not sure why

Comment: i just copied the data in the answer, try with it. Copy it in the clipboard, then use df.read_clipboard as in the screenshot and finally the groupby as in the answer. Hope it works

Comment: The test data from your answer does work now - so that's great! I tried it on my own data after stripping spaces and it still doesn't return properly.

Comment: its a data issue then, at your end

Comment: That would make sense at this point.....do you have any thoughts on what could be wrong with the data?

Comment: try using the strip() for both the date and the quantity fields. Are you reading it as a csv or some DB, how are you getting this data? bcs here in the example it was copy/pasted. if possible for you to share it, then please do and I take a look at it

Comment: This is the dataset I'm using, it's in a CSV - https://easyupload.io/9ur91x

Comment: i just tried it out and here is the resultset - https://easyupload.io/8x8z6p

Comment: There are missing ship-dates, so those are appearing as blank and towards the top of the resultset. it seemed to have worked. right?

Comment: ```
code used

df=pd.read_csv(r'onorder_data.csv')    
   
df.groupby(['Material','Ship Date']).sum().sort_values('Ship Date').reset_index()

```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I want. For whatever reason, the exact code doesn't output that in my IDE. That's super frustrating. Well, I appreciate your help! Good to know that the code works and it's simply something else wrong.

Comment: just a thought, try it out on your colleague computer or setup another virtual environment on your machine or use some oneline jupyter notebook or write it as a python script and execute it.  You need to google on how to go about these possible options